# Как сделать фотографии как в ВК?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, html, css

У меня на сайте фотографии просто выводиться из базы данных на странице, а как сделать так чтобы можно было кликать на отображаемую фотографию и после чего она увеличивалась на этой же странице, и так же можно было листать их. Предупреждаю сразу, в jquery, js слаб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь уже готовыми плагинами фотогалерей к `jQuery`, например `fancybox`, прост в настройке.

Comment: И в правду прост и легок)